# How to stop crazy guy input a lot of keyword for search terms and show up the wrong suggestion?

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, registration, search-terms, key

Did anyone else meet up this situation before? even user registration！

Comment: You can not stop it, but if you think that is happening from a particular IP, you can block that IP to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks for a recommend Piyush, I am going to try it.